# Average of Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have three dataframes with the same index and same columns names (some columns are strings others are numeric): df1, df2, df3.

df1

```
Hour | X1 | X2 | X3 | X4
 0   | 10 | H | 2   | -1  
 1   | 10 | b | 1   | 0 
 2   | 10 | D | 1   | 0 
 3   | 20 | L | 1   | 0
```

df2

```
Hour | X1 | X2 | X3 | X4
 0   | 10 | H | 1   | 1  
 1   | 10 | b | 1   | 0 
 2   | 10 | D | 1   | 0 
 3   | 20 | L | 2   | 0
```

df3

```
Hour | X1 | X2 | X3 | X4
 0   | 10 | H  | 0  |  0  
 1   | 10 | b  | 0  |  0 
 2   | 10 | D  | 0  |  0 
 3   | 20 | L  | 0  |  30
```

I want a new dataframe that is the average of these dataframes for numeric values but keep the string colum as is (all string columns are the same).

df4 =

```
Hour | X1 | X2 | X3 | X4
 0   | 10 | H | 1 | 0  
 1   | 10 | b | 1 | 0 
 2   | 10 | D | 1 | 0 
 3   | 20 | L | 1 | 10
```

I prefer to do it using add function as I have to write a for loop to access each data frame. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Doing with `concat` then `agg`

```
pd.concat([df1,df2,df3]).groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x : x.mean() if x.dtype=='int64' else x.head(1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) to separate numeric and non-numeric series. Then use `pd.concat` with `groupby` + `mean`. Finally, join fixed series and reindex columns.

```
fixed = df1.select_dtypes(include=['object'])
numcols = df1.columns.difference(fixed.columns)

res = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).reindex(columns=numcols)\
        .groupby(level=0).mean()\
        .join(fixed).reindex(columns=df1.columns)

print(res)

   Hour    X1   X2        X3     X4
0    0.0  10.0   H   1.000000   0.0
1    1.0  10.0   b   0.666667   0.0
2    2.0  10.0   D   0.666667   0.0
3    3.0  20.0   L   1.000000  10.0
```